# How to filter unique records depending to some condition by SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with a table that gets data from Time and Attendance devices.

It looks like this:

| ID | UserID | Date | Time | SignDirection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1988781 | 25000 | 2022/01/11 | 10:02 | 1 |
| 1988782 | 25000 | 2022/01/11 | 10:03 | 1 |
| 1988783 | 25000 | 2022/01/11 | 10:04 | 1 |
| 1988784 | 25000 | 2022/01/11 | 12:30 | 2 |
| 1988785 | 25000 | 2022/01/11 | 12:31 | 2 |
| 1988786 | 25001 | 2022/01/11 | 10:00 | 1 |
| 1988787 | 25001 | 2022/01/11 | 12:30 | 2 |
| 1988788 | 25002 | 2022/01/11 | 10:15 | 1 |
| 1988789 | 25002 | 2022/01/11 | 10:16 | 1 |
| 1988790 | 25002 | 2022/01/11 | 12:19 | 2 |

How to filter the data for each User ID to have lower time for SignDirection = 1, and the higher time for SignDirection = 2 ?

To be like :

| ID | UserID | Date | Time | SignDirection |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1988781 | 25000 | 2022/01/11 | 10:02 | 1 |
| 1988785 | 25000 | 2022/01/11 | 12:31 | 2 |
| 1988786 | 25001 | 2022/01/11 | 10:00 | 1 |
| 1988787 | 25001 | 2022/01/11 | 12:30 | 2 |
| 1988788 | 25002 | 2022/01/11 | 10:15 | 1 |
| 1988790 | 25002 | 2022/01/11 | 12:19 | 2 |

I have tried

```sql
select distinct
```

but had no success with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The answer given by @LukStorms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70685750/14868997) is good, but it requires another sort for the second row-number.

You can instead use `LEAD` with the same sort to detect the last row

```sql
SELECT
  ID,
  UserID,
  [Date],
  [Time],
  SignDirection
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, SignDirection, [Date] ORDER BY [Time]) rn_asc
    , LEAD(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, SignDirection, [Date] ORDER BY [Time]) nextTime
    FROM YourTable t
) q
WHERE ((SignDirection = 1 AND rn_asc = 1) OR
       (SignDirection = 2 AND nextTime IS NULL)) 
ORDER BY
  ID,
  UserID,
  [Date],
  [Time],
  SignDirection;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d11c29192c8f43903054d6a648aa14aa)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate 2 `row_number`, up & down.
Then filter on them.

```
SELECT ID, UserID, [Date], [Time], SignDirection
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, SignDirection, [Date] ORDER BY [Time] ASC) rn_asc
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, SignDirection, [Date] ORDER BY [Time] DESC) rn_desc
    FROM your_time_and_attendance_table t
) q
WHERE ((SignDirection = 1 AND rn_asc = 1) OR
       (SignDirection = 2 AND rn_desc = 1)) 
ORDER BY ID, UserID, [Date], [Time], SignDirection
```